# $V(f)\subset V(f,g)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I didn't understand this part in this proof:

[image]

For me, we have to have the contrary $V(f,g)\subset V(g)$. Maybe the author made a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JesseMadnick it's not a book, it's some notes of algebraic geometry, it's really good notes for a beginner.

Comment: Yes, they look very good. Can you provide a link or a reference, please?

Comment: @JesseMadnick of course: https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/calmost/pdfs/pm464_lec.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, yes, you have $V(f,g) \subset V(f)$ and not $V(f) \subset V(f,g)$. But here, there is a special situation:

Let $g \in I(V(f))$.

That means that $g$ vanishes on $V(f)$, or $V(f) \subset V(g)$, and hence here you have $V(f,g) = V(f)$.

Comment: just another question, why in the corollary $V(f)$ is irreducible? the author didn't mention this in the proof.

Comment: I must admit that my knowledge of algebraic geometry is sparse, but iirc, the vanishing set of an irreducible polynomial is irreducible.